# How to handle additional attributes in join tables with sequelize fixtures?

Tags: node.js, database, sequelize.js, fixtures, seeding

I am seeding a database with sequelize fixtures and I am already aware how to treat many-to-many relations with it:

```
Project.hasMany(User);
User.hasMany(Project);
[
    {
        "model":"User",
        "data":{
            "id": 123,
            "name": "John"
        }
    },
    {
        "model":"Project",
        "data": {
            "id": 20,
            "name": "The Great Project",
            "UserProjects": [123]
        }
    }
]
```

But what if the join table has additional attributes like:

```
User = sequelize.define('user', {})
Project = sequelize.define('project', {})
UserProjects = sequelize.define('userProjects', {
    status: DataTypes.STRING
})

User.belongsToMany(Project, { through: UserProjects })
Project.belongsToMany(User, { through: UserProjects })
```

If I use the fixture above, status will be null after loading the fixture because it does not take the status attribute into account. How can I use sequelize-fixtures to seed the status attribute of the join table UserProjects as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This now can be done in v. 0.5.1 of sequelize-fixtures using a special `_through` key for the m2m relationship:

```
[
    {
        "model":"User",
        "data":{
            "id": 123,
            "name": "John"
        }
    },
    {
        "model":"Project",
        "data": {
            "id": 20,
            "name": "The Great Project",
            "users":[
               {
                    "id": 123,
                    "_through": {
                        "status": "active"
                    }
               }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```